# why not specify a specific package version in package.json file? Then we don't need the package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to NPM, sorry if my questions sounds stupid. Below is my question:

Q1-

When I install a package and specify a specified version, for example:

> npm install xxx@3.5.1

but why in the package.json file, it becomes:

```
{
   "devDependencies": {
      "xxx": "^3.5.1"
   }
}
```

I know that the extra caret (the ^ character) will accept versions like  3.5.2, 3.6.0 but not 4.0.0. But I did explicitly specify that I want version 3.5.1, so why NPM still add `^` in front of the version?

Q2-

If NPM install package with version which I what users specify, then we don't need the package-lock.json file, do we? Since all versions in the package.json file are unique and unambiguous?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question. While it is technically possible to define the exact versions of packages directly in the package.json file, the package-lock.json file still serves important purposes and offers benefits even in such cases.

when working with dependencies, it's essential to consider that each package may depend on other dependencies, referred to as nested dependencies. In the package.json file, you can specify the exact version of the main dependency/package, but you cannot explicitly define the version numbers of all the nested dependencies.

The package-lock.json file plays a crucial role in addressing this issue. It captures the precise versions of all dependencies, including the nested ones, ensuring that the entire dependency tree remains consistent. By locking the version numbers of the nested dependencies, the package-lock.json file guarantees that everyone working on the project uses the same versions, regardless of the version ranges specified in the package.json file.

I hope this answers your question.
To understand more about npm and package.json, you can refer to this blog [all about npm](https://medium.com/@ruchivora16/all-about-npm-a3183edabb2)

Answer (score 1):

1.

You can add `--save-exact`

`npm install lodash --save --save-exact` - installs the latest version and saves the exact version in the dependencies in the package.json.

2.

`^` and `~` is the way `npm` offer to you to get the `latest` source of dependencies. It's risky sometimes though.

Read this for more detailed explanation. https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/

Comment: so let's say  if NPM is designed to install and record specified version provided by users, then we don't need package-lock.json, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. I guess so. Since all the dependency's versions in `node_modules` are the same in `package.json`